# How can I change the color of a list of icons according to percentage value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of 10 icons and I want to change the color of the icons according to a given percentage value. For example value = 53 then change color of the first 5 icons in the list or value = 98 change color of the 9 icons.

```css
 var malePercentage = 73;

    var start = 0;
    var count = 1; 

    while(start <= malePercentage){

        $("#demographic-male > i:nth-child("+count+") ").css("color", "red");
        start += 10;
        count++;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demographic-male">
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
    </p>
```

I tried this but when the value is 73 it changed the color of 8 icons not 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that, you can combine `Math.floor()` with the `:lt()` selector:

```js
var malePercentage = 73;

$("#demographic-male > i:lt("+Math.floor(malePercentage / 10)+")" ).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" />
<p id="demographic-male">
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-male"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Another thing if I want the color of the first icon to change when the value is below 10 how will I do that? Can I just do an if condition?

Comment: @j.ian.le Yes, exactly that's probably the best way.